# out of memory when allocating native memory

Tags: android, memory-management, opengl-es, native

I am loading many textures into an (Open GL) app (hundreds of megabytes uncompressed in memory) so I use LRU cache and discard them when needed. In Android the Open GL textures are allocated in the native heap, so I can use all the available memory.

The problems are that...

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)VhbApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
memoryInfo.availMem
```

the *availMem* reports weird number on some devices: Galaxy tab 10.1 with 3.2 - 160MiB and system shows 300MiB free, Acer Iconia Tab A200 with 4.0.3 reports the same value for free memory as the system ~400MiB. The second problem is that on that Acer I get out of memory errors (not in the form of OutOfMemoryError that can be caught as an exception. then it just hits a SIGSEGV) even when allocating textures of size less than 200MiB. Not always, but if the app runs long enough that some textures are deleted from the cache and new ones are loaded, then the app can crash.

So I cannot set the cache size in a very robust way. Those random OOM crashes are only with the Acer. My other devices like Galaxy tab 10.1, Nexus 7 and even Galaxy note (the 5") I do get these random crashes. I properly delete the Open GL textures.

Is there some limit that Acer put into their Androids that limits not only the VM memory size, but also native heap allocation? Or is it a buggy Open GL driver? That Acer an Galaxy tab use almost the same Tegra 2 GPU.

How can I robustly set the cache size? And I need at least 100MiB. Or any other way to robustly allocate 100-200 MiB of textures into an Android Open GL application?